# How to map a Spring Data JPA repository entity into a view model?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mapping

Here is the situation, I want to fetch an entity from database and map it to a new view domain model which has more or less properties, if this view model has more properties, signs the extra properties with default value. I want a map technique in JPA to complete this, which is similar to MyBatis mapping mechanism.
**So how to do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load the entity, copy it over in the new entity, fill the unset properties with the desired default values and store it using JPA (possibly via Spring Data JPA).

For copying over the data from one entity to another you might want to look int `Dozer` or similar libraries.

You could also misuse Spring Data's projection support to query the original entity, but return it as the target entity with methods similar to the following:

```
interface SourceRepository<Source, Long> extends CrudRepository<Source, Long> {
    List<Target> findTargetBy();
}
```

The resulting `Target` entities then could be stored again using another repository (you might have to set version and id properties to `null` to make it clear to the framework that these are new entities.